# Export Addresses Not Found in Google My Maps

Tags: geocoding, google-mymaps

So I was curious if it is possible to highlight and export the addresses that Google My Maps did not successfully geocode. It does not appear that you can even highlight multiple rows at a time to even copy and paste the data into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the you need use control c to copy rather than right click and in excel you need to use paste special and paste as text in order to you to copy and paste data from Google My Maps into Excel.